# Finding duplicates in given list of files

Tags: java, unit-testing, file-system

I implemented a simple tool to find duplicate files, by applying the following strategy:

- Take a list of files and return the sets of duplicates (set of sets)
- Implement a custom `Comparator<File>` to compare files by content
- Implement another comparator that calls the first one, and when two files are equal, mark them as duplicates, using a "duplicate tracker" helper class
- Pass the list of files to `Collections.sort`, using the custom comparator with the duplicate tracker. The goal of sort algorithms is to reduce the number of comparisons, which seems to suit well for my purpose too.

The main method calling the other pieces:

```
public class DuplicateFileFinder {

    /**
     * Find duplicates in given list of files, ignoring I/O errors
     *
     * @param files the list of files to check
     * @return sets of duplicate files
     */
    public Set<Set<File>> findDuplicates(List<File> files) {
        DuplicateTracker<File> tracker = new DuplicateTracker<>();
        Comparator<File> comparator = new FileContentComparator();

        Collections.sort(files, (file1, file2) -> {
            int cmp = comparator.compare(file1, file2);
            if (cmp == 0) {
                tracker.add(file1, file2);
            }
            return cmp;
        });
        return tracker.getDuplicates();
    }
}
```

The `Comparator<File>` to compare files by content, ignoring I/O errors:

```
/**
 * A comparator to compare two files by content.
 * In case of I/O errors, fall back to default comparator of File.
 */
public class FileContentComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFSIZE = 1024 * 1024;
    private final int bufSize;

    public FileContentComparator() {
        bufSize = DEFAULT_BUFSIZE;
    }

    public FileContentComparator(int bufSize) {
        this.bufSize = bufSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        int cmpFileSize = Long.compare(file1.length(), file2.length());
        if (cmpFileSize != 0) {
            return cmpFileSize;
        }

        if (file1.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[bufSize];
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bufSize];

        try (BufferedInputStream stream1 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file1));
             BufferedInputStream stream2 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file2))) {
            int bytesRead1;
            int bytesRead2;

            while (true) {
                bytesRead1 = stream1.read(buffer1);
                bytesRead2 = stream2.read(buffer2);

                assert bytesRead1 == bytesRead2;

                if (bytesRead1 == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                int cmpBuffers = compareBuffers(buffer1, buffer2, bytesRead1);
                if (cmpBuffers != 0) {
                    return cmpBuffers;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore I/O errors, fall back to default comparison logic
            return file1.compareTo(file2);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private int compareBuffers(byte[] buffer1, byte[] buffer2, int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            int cmp = Byte.compare(buffer1[i], buffer2[i]);
            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The class to track duplicates:

```
/**
 * Track objects that are considered duplicates.
 * (Completely unrelated to logical equality by .equals, or identity by ==)
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class DuplicateTracker<T> {

    private final Map<T, Set<T>> pools = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(T item1, T item2) {
        Set<T> pool1 = pools.get(item1);
        Set<T> pool2 = pools.get(item2);

        if (pool1 == null && pool2 == null) {
            pool1 = new HashSet<>();
            pool1.add(item1);
            pool1.add(item2);
            pools.put(item1, pool1);
            pools.put(item2, pool1);
        } else if (pool1 == null) {
            pool2.add(item1);
            pools.put(item1, pool2);
        } else if (pool2 == null) {
            pool1.add(item2);
            pools.put(item2, pool1);
        } else if (pool1 != pool2) {
            pool1.addAll(pool2);
            for (T item : pool2) {
                pools.put(item, pool1);
            }
            pool2.clear();
        }
    }

    public Set<Set<T>> getDuplicates() {
        Set<Set<T>> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
        duplicates.addAll(pools.values());
        return duplicates;
    }
}
```

Unit tests for the duplicate finder:

```
public class DuplicateFileFinderTest {

    private final DuplicateFileFinder duplicateFileFinder = new DuplicateFileFinder();

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tmpDir = new TemporaryFolder();

    private File createTempFileWithContent(String content) throws IOException {
        File file = tmpDir.newFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append(content);
        writer.close();
        return file;
    }

    private Set<File> toSet(File... files) {
        Set<File> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(files));
        return set;
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_no_duplicates() throws IOException {
        File file1 = createTempFileWithContent("foo");
        File file2 = createTempFileWithContent("bar");

        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(file1, file2);

        assertEquals(0, duplicateFileFinder.findDuplicates(files).size());
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_2_of_2_duplicates() throws IOException {
        String content = "blah";

        File file1 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file2 = createTempFileWithContent(content);

        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(file1, file2);

        Set<Set<File>> duplicates = Collections.singleton(toSet(file1, file2));
        assertEquals(duplicates, duplicateFileFinder.findDuplicates(files));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_5_of_5_duplicates() throws IOException {
        String content = "blah";

        File file1 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file2 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file3 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file4 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file5 = createTempFileWithContent(content);

        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(file1, file2, file3, file4, file5);

        Set<Set<File>> duplicates = Collections.singleton(toSet(file1, file2, file3, file4, file5));
        assertEquals(duplicates, duplicateFileFinder.findDuplicates(files));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_2_of_3_duplicates() throws IOException {
        String content = "blah";
        String differentContent = "balm";

        File file1 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file2 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file3 = createTempFileWithContent(differentContent);

        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(file1, file2, file3);

        Set<Set<File>> duplicates = Collections.singleton(toSet(file1, file2));
        assertEquals(duplicates, duplicateFileFinder.findDuplicates(files));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_2_sets_of_duplicates_among_5() throws IOException {
        String content = "blah";
        String anotherContent = "balm";
        String yetAnotherContent = "bulk";

        File file1 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file2 = createTempFileWithContent(content);
        File file3 = createTempFileWithContent(anotherContent);
        File file4 = createTempFileWithContent(anotherContent);
        File file5 = createTempFileWithContent(yetAnotherContent);

        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(file1, file2, file3, file4, file5);

        Set<Set<File>> duplicates = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                toSet(file1, file2),
                toSet(file3, file4)
        ));
        assertEquals(duplicates, duplicateFileFinder.findDuplicates(files));
    }
}
```

Unit tests for the duplicate tracker:

```
public class DuplicateTrackerTest {
    static class Item {
        // Inherits default .equals and .hashCode
        // -> instances will not be equal, with distinct hash code
    }

    private DuplicateTracker<Item> newTracker() {
        return new DuplicateTracker<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_create_common_pool_for_2_items() {
        DuplicateTracker<Item> tracker = newTracker();
        tracker.add(new Item(), new Item());

        Set<Set<Item>> duplicates = tracker.getDuplicates();
        assertEquals(1, duplicates.size());
        assertEquals(2, duplicates.iterator().next().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void should_create_common_pool_for_3_items() {
        DuplicateTracker<Item> tracker = newTracker();
        Item item = new Item();
        tracker.add(item, new Item());
        tracker.add(item, new Item());

        Set<Set<Item>> duplicates = tracker.getDuplicates();
        assertEquals(1, duplicates.size());
        assertEquals(3, duplicates.iterator().next().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_pool_of_second_when_exists() {
        DuplicateTracker<Item> tracker = newTracker();
        Item item = new Item();
        tracker.add(item, new Item());
        tracker.add(new Item(), item);

        Set<Set<Item>> duplicates = tracker.getDuplicates();
        assertEquals(1, duplicates.size());
        assertEquals(3, duplicates.iterator().next().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void should_create_distinct_pools_for_2_pairs_of_items() {
        DuplicateTracker<Item> tracker = newTracker();
        tracker.add(new Item(), new Item());
        tracker.add(new Item(), new Item());

        Set<Set<Item>> duplicates = tracker.getDuplicates();
        assertEquals(2, duplicates.size());

        Iterator<Set<Item>> iterator = duplicates.iterator();
        assertEquals(2, iterator.next().size());
        assertEquals(2, iterator.next().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void should_merge_pools() {
        DuplicateTracker<Item> tracker = newTracker();

        Item ofPool1 = new Item();
        Item ofPool2 = new Item();

        tracker.add(ofPool1, new Item());
        tracker.add(ofPool2, new Item());
        tracker.add(ofPool1, ofPool2);

        Set<Set<Item>> duplicates = tracker.getDuplicates();
        assertEquals(1, duplicates.size());
        assertEquals(4, duplicates.iterator().next().size());
    }
}
```

I'm looking for any and all suggestions to do this better, including testing.

A command line client is in the works, but not ready yet. The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/janosgyerik/java-dupfinder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default comparison logic is `File.compareTo`, which compares
pathnames.  That doesn't seem too useful when comparing file contents.

I guess the assert is fine if you disregard the race condition between
looking at the file size and reading the file; then again, the
stacktrace in that case wouldn't be too user friendly.

For the `compareBuffers` function I'd look for some function that
operates on more than a single byte per iteration.  Possibly only
comparing for equality till a mismatch occurs and only then checking
with `Byte.compare`.

The `HashSet` in `getDuplicates` could be constructed by passing the
values directly into the constructor, same for the `toSet` method.

That said I agree with computing some checksum to improve performance.

Comment: The default comparison logic is used only when an I/O error occurs while comparing content. What alternative would you propose? For comparing byte arrays, I looked for a library function to avoid manual comparison bye by byte but couldn't find.

Comment: For I/O errors I'd probably discard the offending file completely and log it. For comparing byte arrays I had a look and also couldn't find a pre-made solution, but maybe I'm looking for the wrong keywords. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer-- seems like an option by comparing 4 bytes at a time - but depending on what the JVM does it wouldn't have to be faster ...

Answer (score 7):

For real use, you normally want to avoid directly comparing file contents as much as possible.

To do that, you do testing in at least two tiers, and possibly three. First you compare the file sizes. If they're different, the files are different and you're done. Most file systems store file sizes directly, so you can retrieve it very quickly, and since it's only one number the comparison is very fast.

From there you have an (optional) second comparison. This is especially applicable if (for example) the two sets of files are physically remote from each other, so it's fairly cheap to read both files (locally) but much more expensive to transmit them for comparison. In this case, you can do a hash on each file, and compare the hashes.

Then, if the previous test(s) matched, you can do a full comparison of the two files. Or maybe you don't bother--if you use serious cryptographic hash (e.g., SHA-512) for the intermediate comparison, it may not be worth bothering to compare the full contents--the chances of finding a collision with SHA-512 are so minuscule you may not consider it worth the bother. On the other hand, if you used something like a 16-bit (or even 32-bit) CRC as your "hash", you nearly need more to confirm an apparent duplicate.

Comment: Note that I *do* compare the sizes first, before even opening anything. If they matched, I read the files chunk by chunk in parallel, as long as they are matching. So most often the content will not be fully read, only for duplicates. I considered hashing as well, but forgot to explain why it's omitted for now.

Answer (score 1):

Some other points, besides to the already nice answers:

### Hashing chunks

If you want to reduce the total IO / byte comparisons, you could store a hash of each of the chunks as list with the file.

So that if you need to compare two files, you only need to read file 2 and calculate the hash of the first chunk. If that does not match the hash of the first chunk of file 1, you know they are different.

### Chunk size

I would also make the first few chunks a lot smaller, more like the typical page size of you storage device. 4k seems a good fit. (instead of 1MB)

### Java Memory mapped files

It might be worth to check memory-mapped-files, so the OS will help you with the caching of file-content:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/29113714/461499

### Arrays.equals()

I would use the `Arrays.equals()` to compare two arrays as that will use intrinsics of the JVM which might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can optionally compare the file extensions if that fits your use case.  This could cut down on the comparisons by file contents.
2. This code:

   ```
    public Set<Set<T>> getDuplicates() {
        Set<Set<T>> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
        duplicates.addAll(pools.values());
        return duplicates;
    }
   ```

   can be simplified to:

   ```
    public Set<Set<T>> getDuplicates() {
        return new HashSet<>(pools.values());
    }
   ```